# Get retry time from logs table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table structure of logs table

| id | reference_id | service_name | type | data | created_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 504 | 7cb54c325450b4bc26 | CC_VERIFY_REGISTRATION | 0 | {{response_data}} | 2020-09-14 07:53:42 |
| 505 | 7cb54c325450b4bc26 | CC_VERIFY_REGISTRATION | 0 | {{response_data}} | 2020-09-15 17:13:09 |
| 506 | 7cb54c325450b4bc26 | MOBILE_VERIFY | 0 | {{response_data}} | 2020-09-20 7:53:42 |

This is the sample data. With this reference id ,many services logs are registered.  CC_VERFIY_REGISTRATION service failed, hence 2 entries as one denotes latest entry. How do I identify last retry time of ANY API for a particular **reference_id**

```sql
select created_on
        ,service_name 
from thirdparty_service_logs tsl  
where reference_id ='7cb54c325450b4bc26'
group by service_name ,created_on
```

This gives the latest created_on for each service. But looking for latest created_on for reference_id . In this case, though the latest api call is for MOBILE_VERIFY, i'm looking for  id 505's **created_date column**  as output

Comment: *This gives the latest created_on for each service*. No, it doesn't. You're grouping unique records  because `created_on` is unique. That aside, from your description it's not clear why you don't simply filter out records having `service_name  = MOBILE_VERIFY`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `CTE` to prefetch `reference_id` and the corresponding `max(created_on)` according to your retry criteria, and then use it to get the target rows.

```
With CTE As (
    Select reference_id, Max(created_on) As Lst
    From thirdparty_service_logs
    Group by reference_id
    Having Count(*)>1)
Select *
From thirdparty_service_logs As t
Where Exists (Select * From CTE Where reference_id=t.reference_id And lst=t.created_on)
Order by reference_id
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32c77684d7f9a2228e7adc7e482488a5)

Result:

| id | reference_id | service_name | type | data | created_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 506 | 7cb54c325450b4bc26 | MOBILE_VERIFY | 0 | {{response_data}} | 2020-09-20 07:53:42.000 |

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last but, one record for the reference_id as given below:

```sql
declare @table table(id int,    reference_id varchar(50),   service_name varchar(50),   type int,   data varchar(50),   created_on datetime)

INSERT INTO @Table values
(504    ,'7cb54c325450b4bc26','CC_VERIFY_REGISTRATION', 0   ,'{{response_data}}','2020-09-14T07:53:42'),
(505    ,'7cb54c325450b4bc26','CC_VERIFY_REGISTRATION', 0   ,'{{response_data}}','2020-09-15T17:13:09'),
(506    ,'7cb54c325450b4bc26','MOBILE_VERIFY',  0           ,'{{response_data}}','2020-09-20T07:53:42');


SELECT top 1 * FROM @table  as ot where reference_id = '7cb54c325450b4bc26'
and created_on < (SELECT max(created_on) from @table as it where it.reference_id = ot.reference_id)
order by created_on desc
```

| id | reference_id | service_name | type | data | created_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 505 | 7cb54c325450b4bc26 | CC_VERIFY_REGISTRATION | 0 | {{response_data}} | 2020-09-15 17:13:09.000 |